# Launch py-shell command in another emacs window

Tags: emacs, python-mode

When using `python-mode` in Emacs, I first split the screen via <kbd>C-x 3</kbd>.
I'd like to be able do <kbd>C-c !</kbd> to launch `py-shell` in the *other* window, not in the window currently active. How can I configure Emacs to do that without having to switch windows with <kbd>C-x o</kbd> before launching the shell?

I'm using Emacs 24.3.1, and I've got all my configuration files in `~/.emacs.d`.

I just installed the `python-mode` package using `package-install` with the Marmalade repository, and I haven't yet edited any `.el` file related to `python-mode`.

Comment: please what is your version of emacs ?

Comment: just edited the question with more info, Thanks!

Comment: Record a macro, save it in the `init.el` or `.emacs` and make a keybinding for it.

Comment: But I'd like to use C-c !, which is already on use in python-mode, and I can't locate where the binding is defined. Will the macro override it?

Comment: @MartíBosch You can specify in your configuration whether you want to use `C-c !` or for the macro or a different key binding, see my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21056602/1199226). To check which function a specific key binding is bound to, use `C-h k`; if you know the name of a function but not its binding, use `C-h w`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BleedingFingers says you can simply use a macro and bind that to a key. It's up to you whether or not you want to re-use the <kbd>C-c !</kbd> binding for the macro or bind it to a different key.

Here's how to proceed should you decide to go with the macro option, starting with Emacs showing only a single window:

#### Define macro

<kbd>F3</kbd>

<kbd>C-x 3</kbd>

<kbd>C-x o</kbd>

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `py-shell` <kbd>RET</kbd>

<kbd>C-x o</kbd>

<kbd>F4</kbd>

#### Assign name to macro

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `name-last-kbd-macro` <kbd>RET</kbd> `py-shell-other-window` <kbd>RET</kbd>

You can replace `py-shell-other-window` with whatever name you would like to use for the macro.

#### Add macro to your configuration

Open your configuration file, move point (cursor) to an empty line and do

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-kbd-macro` <kbd>RET</kbd>

This will insert the macro definition into your configuration file.

#### Bind macro to key

Add the following code to your configuration file to bind the macro to a key in `python-mode`:

```lisp
(require 'python-mode) ; Make sure python-mode-map is available
                       ; for modification
(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c !") nil) ; Unset default binding 
                                               ; for C-c !
                                               ; (not necessary if you choose an
                                               ; unused binding)
(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c !") 'py-shell-other-window) ; Bind macro to C-c !
```

#### Turn key binding on

Mark the lines added in the previous step and run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-region` <kbd>RET</kbd>, or simply restart Emacs.

#### Celebrate :)

Answer (score 0):

Advice lets you redefine code in other libraries on-the-fly.

```lisp
(defadvice py-shell (around auto-split activate)
    (split-window-right)
    (other-window)
    ,ad-do-it
    (other-window))
```

Variations apply.